Passing parameters to a pytest fixture that also needs cleanup
I've defined a fixture that accepts arguments to be used in an integration style test that requires some teardown upon completion. It looks something like this:
@pytest.fixture
def create_user_in_third_party():
   from clients import third_party_client

   def _create_user_in_third_party(user: User):
       third_party_client.create_user(user)

   return _create_user_in_third_party

However, we then would like to clean up the created user once the test's lifecycle is complete. In a standard fixture, that may look like:
@pytest.fixture
def create_user():
   user = User(name="Jim")
   user.save()
   yield user
   user.delete()

When applying that same paradigm to the fixture that takes args above, I am not seeing the fixture being called at all (returns a generator that isn't exercising the inner method code).
That code (not working) looks like this:
def create_user_in_third_party():
   from clients import third_party_client

   def _create_user_in_third_party(user: User):
       third_party_client.create_user(user)
       yield # give back control to caller
       third_party_client.delete_user(user)

   return _create_user_in_third_party

is it possible to achieve the above without having to break up creation and deletion into two different fixtures ?

Using the docs that Andrej linked above: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#factories-as-fixtures , we can use the factory pattern approach to accrue created entities and delete them later. So it ends up looking like this:
@pytest.fixture
def create_user_in_third_party():
   from clients import third_party_client
   created_users = []

   def _create_user_in_third_party(user: User):
       third_party_client.create_user(user)
       created_users.append(user)

   yield _create_user_in_third_party
   for user in created_users:
       third_party_client.delete(user)


According to the documentation you can pass data to fixture using markers, e.g.:
test.py
import pytest


class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def save(self):
        pass

    def delete(self):
        pass

@pytest.fixture
def create_user(request):

    marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("db_username")
    if marker is None:
        name = 'Jim'
    else:
        name = marker.args[0]

    
    user = User(name=name)
    user.save()
    yield user
    user.delete()


@pytest.mark.db_username('John')
def test_user(create_user):
    assert create_user.name == 'John'

Also register mark in pytest.ini.
pytest.ini
[pytest]
markers =
    db_username: data for create_user fixture


Running pytest test.py:
(venv) $ pytest test.py 
================= test session starts =================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-8.2.0, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /app/pytest-test
configfile: pytest.ini
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                  

test.py .                                                       [100%]

========================================== 1 passed in 0.00s ==========================================


Thanks! This is not quite what I was looking for because User would be difficult to send without referencing other fixtures. Using this pattern: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html#factories-as-fixtures works well for what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

You can use addfinalizer to run the delete use logic at the teardown
@pytest.fixture
def create_user_in_third_party(request):
    from clients import third_party_client

    def _create_user_in_third_party(user: User):
        def _delete_user():
            third_party_client.delete_user(user)

        third_party_client.create_user(user)
        request.addfinalizer(_delete_user)

    yield _create_user_in_third_party


def test_user(create_user_in_third_party):
    user = User()
    create_user_in_third_party(user)

